# Shortcut for a = b + a;

Tags: javascript

So I've realised that `a += b;` is actually `a = a + b;`. (Try replacing `a`, `b` with strings.)

Is there a shortcut for `a = b + a;`? I've tried `a =+ b;` but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: No there is no such shortcut.

Comment: Are you using `+` for string concatenation? If you're using it for addition, it doesn't matter because addition is commutative.

Comment: @PeterOlson: Yes, obviously. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For std::string, `operator+=` is an operator performed on the lhs argument that alters the argument and returns a reference. Since `operator+` for strings means "append", there is no possibility for you to have an such an operator for the other way round.

This seems to be an annoying limitation at first, but actually there is a pretty good reason for that. std::string dynamically allocate more memory in the same way vector and other dynamic fields do. (-> constant amortized complexity). This operation always allocates memory at the end. So whenever you want to add something to the beginning of a string, you actually have to alter the argument that will be the new prefix or you have to construct an entirely new string.

`operator+=` forces you to alter the object that will prefix the resulting string. Creating an entirely new object (with memory allocation and completely copying both arguments) shouldn't happen implicitly, anyway. If you want something like `b = a + b` this means that `b` now carries a newly **constructed** string. It's a fresh assignment. `operator+=`, on the other hand, **changes** the left-hand-side argument.

Comment: +1 for solid, yet slightly overcomplicated way of saying that there's no shortcut for `a = b + a;` :)

Answer (score 6):

`a = b + a` means the same thing as `a = a + b`, if dealing with numbers. For strings, there is no similar shortcut.

Comment: Not if a and b are strings! :)

Comment: `+` with strings is concatenation, which isn't commutative.

Comment: @WTK: Yes, I noticed the OP is talking about strings right after posting my answer. Updated. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's shorter way of doing `a = b + a` (when dealing with strings).

Comment: 'a=b+a' is shorter than 'a = b + a'